# How to get all events from an EKCalendar in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, calendar, ios6

I've created a calendar with some events, now I want to get all events from that calendar, without knowing what their start or end date is.

Code I tried, getting all events from all calendars, so I could divide them by calendar ID later or so.. :

```
NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate distantPast] endDate:[NSDate distantFuture] calendars:eventStore.calendars];

NSArray *allEvents = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];
```

This makes `allEvents` return `nil` while the database clearly shows events in the calendar.

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have it working now.

This is the code I'm using:

```
NSDate* endDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSDate distantFuture] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cal];
NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate date] endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray];
NSArray *eventList = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];

for(int i=0; i < eventList.count; i++){

    NSLog(@"Event Title:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] title]);

}
```

Gives me all events from the calendar I'm  using for my app from the date it is right when you call the method.

I think giving `[NSDate distantPast]` won't work because it's in the past or something.. setting your startDate as `[NSDate date]` will work.

Hope this helps people who have the same problem..

Comment: "[NSDate distantPast] won't work because it's in the past or something" saved my day. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to lookup a year span greater than 4 years, the returned events would be trimmed by the system to those from the first 4 years. (see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507479-predicateforevents)). What could be a possible solution is to run the predicate matching in batches.

Here's a C# extension for Xamarin.iOS

```
public static class EKEventStoreExtensions
{        
    private const int MaxPredicateYearSpan = 4;

    public static EKEvent[] GetAllEvents(this EKEventStore eventStore, DateTimeOffset startAt, DateTimeOffset endAt, params EKCalendar[] calendars)
    {
        var isBatched = endAt.Year - startAt.Year >= MaxPredicateYearSpan;
        var result = new List<EKEvent>();
        var batchStartAt = startAt;
        var batchEndAt = endAt;

        while (batchStartAt < endAt)
        {
            if (isBatched)
            {
                batchEndAt = batchStartAt.AddYears(1);
                if (batchEndAt > endAt)
                {
                    batchEndAt = endAt;
                }
            }

            var events = GetEventsMatching(eventStore, batchStartAt, batchEndAt, calendars);
            result.AddRange(events);

            batchStartAt = batchEndAt;
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }

    private static EKEvent[] GetEventsMatching(EKEventStore eventStore, DateTimeOffset startAt, DateTimeOffset endAt, EKCalendar[] calendars)
    {
        var startDate = (NSDate)startAt.LocalDateTime;
        var endDate = (NSDate)endAt.LocalDateTime;
        var fetchCalendarEvents = eventStore.PredicateForEvents(startDate, endDate, calendars);

        return eventStore.EventsMatching(fetchCalendarEvents);
    }
}
```