# Get events from all the EKCalendar

Tags: ekeventkit

I want to get events from all the calendars (home,work,calendar and birthday). I am getting events from the defaultcalendar, but cannot fetch events from Birthday calendar. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934628/849963) might help you:

```
NSDate* endDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSDate distantFuture] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cal];
NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate date] endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray];
NSArray *eventList = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];

for(int i=0; i < eventList.count; i++){

    NSLog(@"Event Title:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] title]);

}
```